# Google Maps -> Displaying only country borders and onclick event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there anyone experienced on Google Maps? I am planning to add a world map to my web service and then display number of statistics for each country I specify.

I can specify map type by "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP" but there's no map type to show country borders only.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.
Mat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Maps allow you to style the maps, ie change the different elements (roads, ...) representations. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps

Here is the full list of styleable elements: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType